# How to interface to more CSI-2 devices than available CSI-2 modules on MPU?

Tags: sensor, microprocessor, camera, interface, image-sensor

the problem is:
I have a MPU which has only 2x CSI-2 modules (each with 4 data lanes), however I want connect to 4 other devices over CSI-2 interface (each device has one CSI-2 module).

So the question is: Is there a solution for accomplishing this design?
[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Bien

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of CSI multiplexer. There are some dedicated part but you could also rig an FPGA to do the switching (in fact there are application notes for this both for Xilinx and Altera/Intel).

Comment: Some links to the mentioned application notes would be helpful.

Comment: Seriously, just type "MIPI multiplexer" or "CSI-2 multiplexer". First result https://www.latticesemi.com/en/Products/DesignSoftwareAndIP/IntellectualProperty/IPCore/IPCores04/4Inputto1OutputMIPICSI2CameraAggregatorBridge

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. 
One question however to the MPI CSI-2 Multiplex. Is the Multiplexer working as a switch, i.e. MPU can only receiving data from a single device at a time?
or can MPU receive data from all 4 devices at the same time ?

Comment: It's a multiplexer, I think you choose one and you receive that. I don't think MIPI could do a 'merged' transmission. You get one frame from one camera, then one from the second one and so one. Unless you need some serious synchronization it shouldn't be a problem (for serious synchronization consider global shutter cameras)

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, thanks for the clarification.